# Elixir "no match of right hand side value" in controller Phoenix

Tags: match, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm using the framework Phoenix with Ecto Mongo and I'm trying to get all Groups(My model) and loop this in view.

```
@groups = Group |> GlobalDocs.Repo.all
```

And I'm getting this message error:

```
no match of right hand side value: [%Group{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, avatar_url: nil, description: "", group_id: 123, id: "585ea2ce6e8dee0a6c04ecf6", name: "TryGroup", slug: "try_group"}]
```

Why this? If I run this in IEx, this code works.

Thanks for this.

Comment: Did you mean `groups = ...`? `@groups` is a module attribute.

Comment: It's only this haha
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Elixir and Phoenix do not work the same way as Ruby and Rails does.

When you use an `@` variable. They are called [module attributes](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html). In Phoenix, you do not use module attributes in order to have a variable accessible in a view like you would with rails.

In Phoenix, you would use something like the following.

```
groups = GlobalDocs.Repo.all(Group)

render conn, "index.html", groups: groups
```

Now, in your view, you will have access to a `@groups` variable.